# Erro EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?
Estou tentando fazer o CodeFirst e quando executo o comando me aparece este erro:

*O inicializador de tipo de 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' acionou uma exceção.*

Meu AppConfig esta assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicasDbConexto" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;Database=musica;uid=root;pwd=''" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>

        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />

        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.17.0" newVersion="8.0.17.0" />

      </dependentAssembly>

    </assemblyBinding>

  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Olá! Você poderia colocar a descrição da exceção adicionada pelo System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig? Aparentemente seu arquivo AppConfig está ok, porém outras coisas podem estar causando este erro. Como por exemplo: com seu banco de dados, com sua classe de contexto, com os tipos do seu modelo, dentre outros. Observe esses pontos e até mesmo a versão do seu Entity Framework.